# Doesn't [UIWindow addSubView:] retain?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Check it:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"Checking login--user value is %@", [defaults valueForKey:@"userID"]);
if ([defaults valueForKey:@"userID"] == NULL){
    LoginViewController *loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
    [window addSubview:loginController.view];
    [loginController release];
}
else {
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
}
```

Every other place when I put a subview into another view, I release that view after I've done that, because it's now owned by the view it's a subview of. HERE, though, when I do `[loginController release]`, every IBAction on that loginController gets called against a deallocated instance. Commenting out that line makes everything work.

I note the difference in approach between my loginController and the navigationController that came with the template; the navigationController is a synthesized property that gets released in `-(void)dealloc{ }`, so it's still around after being put into `window`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-addSubview:` only retains the view, **not** the controller.

Comment: Ah. In retrospect, that's pretty obvious. I was looking at a controllerless view, there. So there's nothing I need to do about managing retain count on the view, then, is there? I guess when it removesItselfFromSuperview, it'll drop back to 1 and then when the controller is released (I'll need to make it a property so I can release it at dealloc time, I guess) it'll go away completely. Is that right?

Comment: @Dan: Yes. (If you want a controller-less view, create a UIView directly.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manually add a controller's view to a view hierarchy as the controller won't be retained and even if retained won't receive the expected system calls (e.g. orientation changes, etc.).

Instead add the controller to a `UIWindow` using its `rootViewController` property.

If you still feel the need to add the controller's view somewhere, then maybe you shouldn't be using view controllers but simple custom views instead.